# return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key) TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a program that calculates your weight on different planets with GUI. This is the code. When I enter the int weight and Str planet I get this error in the console: return self.tk.call (self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
from tkinter import *

def calcular():
    mars = (peso.get()*3.7)/9.8

  
    if "Marte" in planeta:
        res.set("Tu peso en el planeta " + str(planeta.get()) + " es: " + str(mars))
        


        

ventana = Tk()
#StringVar , IntVar, DoubleVar
peso = IntVar()
planeta = StringVar()
res = StringVar()
ventana.geometry("400x300")




#Etiqueta
textoN = Label(ventana,text="Escribe un numero: ")
textoN.place(x=150,y=10)

#Caja de texto
pesoentry = Entry(ventana,textvariable=peso)
pesoentry.place(x=150,y=40)

planeta = Entry(ventana,textvariable=planeta)
planeta.place(x=150,y=60)

#Etiqueta Resultado
textoR = Label(ventana,textvariable=res)
textoR.place(x=150,y=140)

#Boton
boton = Button(ventana,text="Calcular",command=calcular,bg="#006",fg="white")
boton.place(x=180,y=100)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the text of the question is in Spanish. Please either [edit] your question here to be in English, or post it instead on [the Spanish language version of Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Sorry. I changed that.

Comment: `"Marte" in planeta` is not a valid thing to do, when `planeta` is a StringVar - you have to call `.get()` on it to retrieve its actual value, just as you've done several other places in the program.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
def calcular():
    mars = (peso.get()*3.7)/9.8

    if "Marte" in planeta.get():
        res.set("Tu peso en el planeta " + str(planeta.get()) + " es: " + str(mars))
```

the line I changed:

```
if "Marte" in planeta.get():
```

Comment: Essentially speaking, you just have to show the line you changed, posting entire code just bloats your answer unnecessarily.

Comment: @CoolCloud well I show the whole code just in case they can't find that line or sth (oh, wait) ok, fine but I would still like to include some context so that They know where it is I changed since lines can be diffficult to find sometimes (obvs giving the whole code won't help with finding) but if it is a def I would like to include that (will edit a bit)